# Sorry for the incoherence of my previous post, lets try again, I have a doubt please help with it

Tags: allah, doubts, theology

Allah is the cause of all things, and the creator of all things. Allah is eternal, never ending and timeless, with no beginning or end. Him and all of his attributes are eternal and never ending. This might help you understand this question. Do you understand eternality in the abstract sense, do you have any abstraction that allows you to understand eternality? To put it, eternality here means never ending , however its the timeless eternality, something with no beginning and no end, Allah has no beginning and no end, if something has no beginning you can't apply seconds to it to count how long its existed because that doesn't apply to it. Unfortunately I've argued with lots of really dumb people, so I'm just going to say right now that the fact I'm showing a seeming contradiction is showing that I am starting to feel Allah isn't real, because him being the first cause seems to violate the law of non contradiction.

This post is showing a contradiction in the existence of a first cause, meaning maybe its not possible for it to exist. You might not get this immediately so look at the second paragraph and read again, for now just read this:can you get this: a first cause is eternal, meaning it is timeless, never ending. You can't apply seconds to it if it is eternal, all of its processes are eternal, its process of causation is also eternal,, all of its processes are eternal, and its process of causation is eternal, thus since its causation process doesn't end, it will continue to cause forever and ever, being eternal in the timeless sense, without a beginning and end. Now, I say this: if a first causes causation doesn't end, it will continue to cause and cause the exact same thing as its causation of that thing doesn't end, however, this means that the law of identity would be violated, because how can there be two of the same thing , if it continues to cause that thing then that would mean there are two things that are the same, but everything is equal to itself, it would go agains't the law of identity, so how do we overcome this contradiction? I thought of something like,non beings don't have properties, and this is important because of the fact that we can say that our abstract understanding is wrong, but then I thought of this: maybe we can't define the being abstractly since its trancendent, and other things but it seems i need help from smeone else on this.

Mind you, an inherent aspect of a first cause is its ability to cause, and its actual act of causing is also never ending, inherent here means it exists as a permanent aspect of it, because we know causation is an aspect of the first cause that is inherent to it, as if it wasn't permanent it would mean it had an aspect that was added to it, which is impossible because is eternal and timeless and can't change. So its causation being an inherent aspect of it is also eternal, and the process, non timely process which takes place in causing it is also never ending.

Answer (score 1):

As Muslims we know that Allah is Lord of the worlds as stated in the Quran:

> [All] praise is [due] to Allāh, Lord of the worlds (Saheeh International, 1:2)

Source for this Verse: https://quran.com/1:2

From this we know that Allah is the Lord of the worlds, and from this verse in the Quran:

> Allāh is the Creator of all things, and He is, over all things, Disposer of affairs. (Saheeh International, 39:62)

Source for this verse: https://quran.com/39:62

From these verses we know that Allah is the Lord and Creator of all things. So do you think that we can apply our limited three dimensional logic to the workings of the Creator and Lord of the worlds and everything? No, we can't. But we can use our limited logic to come to the understanding that Allah exists, let me give you an example:

We as humans with our limited logical capacity are unable to imagine dimensions  beyond our three dimensions, we might have the ability to use mathematical equations; but that is far from truly understanding the fourth or any higher dimension. But we humans using our limited logic were able to come to the conclusion that these higher dimensions exist. And in the same way using our limited logic we can come to the conclusion that Allah exists, but we cannot truly understand or comprehend him or his being. Laws that can apply to our world cannot necessarily apply to Allah, as in the Quran it is stated:

> Nor is there to Him any equivalent." (Saheeh International, 112:4)

Source for this verse is: https://quran.com/112:4

The fact is that there is nothing similar to Allah, and so if there is nothing that we even know of which is similar to him, then how can you apply the laws and rules of this world that we came up with through the observation of this world to him? We simply cannot, but we can know that he exists through these rules and laws as these rules operate on our level of understanding.